# Can the Feiyu G6 Plus gimbal be used as a remote shooter?

Tags: image-stabilization, shutter-release, triggers

I'm looking forward to getting [this gimbal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F8QKRTC), but have 2 doubts, first, does it act as a remote shooter? what I mean, is on setting a timelapse does the gimbal also takes the pictures? or do I need to use a separate controller to set the shooter, and second, how do I attach this to a tripod? I've been doing some browsing and have only found people using the small "tripod" that comes along, but not using a real tripod, do I need to get anything else?

Comment: If you put the camera on a real tripod anyway, why the stabilized gimbal?

Comment: I decided to go for the gimbal for automated shots (timelapse, etc), and also I do sports shoots outdoors, so I'm looking for a budget tripod and the gimbal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've figured out the gimbal part of your question, so I'll focus on the second half: taking photos automatically for a timelapse.

Some cameras have a timelapse feature built-in, your camera may already have this capability.

If your camera doesn't have a built-in timelapse feature, then you'll want a tool called an **intervalometer**.  An intervalometer is a small device with a cord which plugs into the remote shutter release port on your camera to trigger it to take photos.  You configure the device with the parameters you want for your timelapse (such as "take a photo every 30 seconds until 500 photos are taken"), then press the Start button, and it will use the remote shutter release to take the photos automatically.

Intervalometers often have other features that may also be helpful, such as a self-timer (which can be used to delay the start of your timelapse, OR simply to give a longer delay than your camera's built-in self-timer) and a bulb timer (which will hold down the shutter for a bulb exposure for a specified duration).  They also usually have a "dumb" shutter button that allows you to use it just like a regular remote shutter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, lol, have already forgoten about this question, the only thing I added, was a external power source, for long takes (whole nigth, etc)

Comment: Oh, I only just now noticed that this is 2 years old :D

Answer (score 0):

After some research and reading the specs got to understand that the gimbal itself is almost useless regarding camera control, there are chances that for some models actions like taking a picture can work, but besides that, you cannot do anything, so have to go also for a remote shooter to get time-lapse with movement